# How to loop through date variables in PDI?

Tags: loops, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

So I have a job where first transformation step is "declaring date variables"

and I need to use 2 date variables as a range to create a loop between date_from and today ( 7 days range )

so the next transformation step "temp1" would use the date ranges in a input step to get and run through a loop of last 7 days

First part in  "declaring date variables"  is

[get system info step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP30u.png)

getting start date = week_from > end date = today, however I am lost on how to do the rest through calculation step to increment etc and get 7 days dates

and next part I want know how to use the said dates to run the job through a loop ?

currently I simply get all past 7 days like this :

`and dtJornada >=  '${LAST_WEEK}'  and dtJornada < '${CURRENT_DAY}`

but the new condition I have for this task is to make it a loop so how would the transformation run once through each date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Copy rows to Result** step to loop through the generated date values. You can refer to [this blog post](https://tech-spaghetti.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/) for further details.

Comment: I think I understand the usage of "Copy rows to result' step to generate the range variables however I don't understand how I would be able to loop through them, to essentially loop the transformations and updating the variable each time in the first step ( Query ) would be great if you can explain that part please